# Wireless Keyboard Volume Down acting different

Tags: macos, keyboard

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, on my mac wireless keyboard, has been a couple of days that every time I click on the Volume Down (F10) key, instead of rising down the volume it will move the application.

[I made a small video so you can have an idea.](https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0752plgjGWU8ZM)  How can I change to default factory?

Comment: Go to expose and spaces in System Preferences. Then change the key from F10 to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a change was made to the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key setting. The behavior you are seeing is "Show Desktop", but generally requires pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to activate. (Note on my keyboard Volume Down is F11. It may differ on yours, but the steps below don't chnage.)

To change this behavior:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. In the second section, click on Keyboard, then on the Keyboard tab if necessary.
3. Uncheck "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys."